# Can I directly map the data from an external source on it to persist on DB?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am pretty new in **Spring Data JPA** and ORM in general. I have the following architectural doubt.

Lets consider this entity class:

```java
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class Order {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String fullName;
   private String address;
   private String product;

   @Column(name = "order_date_time")
   private String orderDate;

   private Double quantity;

   // getters, setters 
}
```

This class is mapped on my `order` database table.

In my application data came from an Excel document that I parse via Apace POI and than I have to persist on the database.
My doubt is: can I directly use this entity class to map an Excel row using Apache POI in order to persist the Excel rows as `order` table records? Or is better to use another DTO class to read the rows from Excel and than use this DTO to set the field values of my entity class?

An entity class can contain a constructor using fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From architectural point of view better to have a DTO class and encapsulate some logic there.

```
class CsvOrder {

    private String fullName;

    private String address;

    public CsvRecord(String[] record) {
        fullName = get(record, FULLNAME_INDEX);
        address = get(record, ADDRESS_INDEX);
    }

    public Order toOrder() {
        Order result = new Order();

        result.setFullName(fullName);

        return result;
    }

}

public static <T> T get(T[] arr, int index) {
    final T notFound = null;
    return index < size(arr) ? arr[index] : notFound;
}

public static <T> int size(T[] array) {
    return array == null ? 0 : array.length;
}
```

You can put a static method `toOrder()` to `OrderServiceMapper`, if you want to totally decouple layers

```
class OrderServiceMapper {

    public static Order toOrder(CsvOrder order) {
        Order result = new Order();

        result.setFullName(order.getFullName());

        return result;
    }

}
```

Also, use `Integer` in place of `int` for id. Better to use `Long` everywhere

```
    // This tells Spring to add this class to Hibernate configuration during auto scan
    @Entity 
    public class Order {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I directly use this entity class to map an Excel row using Apache
>   POI in order to persist the Excel rows as order table records?

Yes you can.

> Or is better to use another DTO class to read the rows from Excel and
>   than use this DTO to set the field values of my entity class?

It's certainly common to have a DTO layer between the two, but it's not required so it's up to you.

> An entity class can contain a constructor using fields?

Yes, but at least Hibernate wants a non-private default constructor as well, so remember to create a `protected Order() {}` (or any visibility modifier besides private) in addition to your parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a heavy user of Apache POI, but I do know it's used to manipulate MS files.

So, here are my two cents, in your use case, you can just read it and map directly to the Entity class as it doesn't expose an API to the external world.

However, if you were building a REST/SOAP API, I recommend you put a DTO in between so you don't mistakenly expose things that shouldn't be exposed.